# Simulating an RLC bandpass filter with LTspice

Tags: filter, ltspice, simulation, passive-filter, cutoff-frequency

I have analyzed the filter in question both in practice and in simulation (with LTspice)

[image: rlc filter]

The calculations I performed to determine the high and low cutoff frequency and the resonance frequency are as follows:

- fres = 1/2pi * sqrt(LC)
- fch = R/2pi * L
- fcl = 1/2pi * RC

From these, I obtained:

- fres = ~10kHz
- fch = ~238kHz
- fcl = ~106Hz

The results I obtained coincide with those recorded during the practical test, but not in the simulated one.

Below the trend measured at the node between the inductor and the resistor:

[image]

Now I'm wondering why it behaves this way. Also, since this is a passive filter, shouldn't the maximum gain be 0 dB?

Comment: The answer below is the correct one, but I have to wonder: why did you choose `AC 5` in the first place? I'm interested in the reason.

Comment: the value has been chosen for no particular reason.

Comment: In your honest opinion, do you think that is a healthy attitude when searching for results? Don't forget about the [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigo). As it happens, this wasn't the case, but it did cause you to misinterpret the results.

Comment: I asked for this very reason, unfortunately I did not know that ltspice measured in dbV and I am new to the subject. However I understand the concept and I thank you for the advice, maybe if the situation had been slightly different I would have undoubtedly made a mistake by misinterpreting the results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason the "gain" is above zero is that it's not gain, it's voltage expressed in dBV and you're putting 5 VAC into the circuit. Change your source AC amplitude to 1 and try it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Very helpful, but what is the relationship between db and dbV? How does the conversion take place?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Decibels are a way of expressing signals using logarithms so that you can add and subtract them easily. For dBV the formula is 20 * log10(volts) and 1 volt = 0dBV.

In LTSpice you can right-click on the dB scale on the left and change it to linear to see it in volts. Usually if you're doing an AC analysis you want to use 1 VAC for your source so everything is referenced to 0dB.

You should also notice that your simulated results should now match your calculated results.